# How to fix broken JavaScript behaviour in ownCloud after upgrade?

Tags: javascript, owncloud

I upgraded my self-hosted ownCloud instance from 6 to 7 via the apt packing manager. All calendars, file sync etc. worked correctly after but I haven't been able to log in to the web
interface anymore. I discovered that when I entered my credentials to log in: the `disabled`
attribute remains in the button element.

```
    <input original-title="" id="submit" class="login primary"
value="Log in" disabled="disabled" type="submit">
```

Removing it by hand, I can log in. But then again, most of the elements in the web UI do not trigger actions when clicked on.

I wonder if anybody else experienced this problem and if there's maybe only a single file which is corrupt. Subsequent updates of ownCloud did not solve the problem.

This is a general description of the problem. I'll provide further information, if needed.

Comment: [Owncloud 7 cannot login to web console #9845](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/9845)

Comment: besides the calendar app do you have other apps installed? Try first to disable all 3rd party apps and try again to login. If that doesn't help please look in the browser console for specific errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the third party app "roundcube" made the GUI work again. I first did not disable all and not roundcube because it was the last one I expected to cause troubles.